# Keyboard Input Not Working on iOS 16.5 from App built in Unity

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, keyboard, ios16

I am using Unity 2021.3.25 and building for iOS testing on IOS 16.5. No matter what I do I cannot get my external keyboard connected over Bluetooth to register key strokes.

I can tap on an input field and type just fine, but other than that keys are not detected. I have tried both Unity's default input manager and their newer input system. Neither work. Just to be clear if I press the "A" key for example and I have a function that is supposed to be called when that is pressed down, it will not get called. All the different ways of registering input work fine in editor and in build on Windows, no problems there. Only problems are with iOS. I am at a loss. Am I missing something obvious? Am I the only person having this problem? I know there were problems with keyboard support on iOS 15 but it should be fixed in the version of Unity I am using. Does anyone have any ideas?

Previous Issue: https://issuetracker-mig.prd.it.unity3d.com/issues/keyboard-input-is-not-working-when-using-an-external-keyboard-in-ios-15

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbGoh.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/udWDk.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/J42nh.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWPiP.png)